# Send data from android device USB

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, pic

Is it possible to use the library `jpicusb`, to send information from an android device to a pic?

If this can't be done, can you please tell me how can I send information from the android device to a pic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with "jpicusb".  However you can use the Android Open Accessory (AOA) protocol to send data between an Android device and a PIC.  Microchip.com actually sells a envelopment kit that demonstrates this.  Also, I believe you can use the Android debugging protocol for communication between a PIC and Android device.  I believe this is how the early PIC based IOIO boards worked.  However, Microchip will point out that the latter protocol has changed over Android releases and may not be that official (i.e. could change over time).